# Finding all objects that have the same type object in a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I have a model that has a ManyToMany relationship with itself (a "following" list).

I can pull the list of people any particular person is following (i.e. obj.following.all() ), but I am trying to figure out how to get a list of objects that contain this particular object within THEIR following list.  In other words, I have a following list, and now I want to parse a followers list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  If you want to view an inverse list, just set a 'related_name' and call that.

In the case of:

```
class Person(models.Model){
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name='follow_list')    
}
```

A list of people this person is following:

```
person.following.all()
```

A list of people that are following this person;

```
person.follow_list.all()
```